# SQL replace a string enum in a column of a result set with another string

Tags: sql, database

I apologize if the question is duplicated, but in my preliminary search I haven't found anything!

In my query extraction with SQL, I need to replace the result of a column with other string values.

In particular, I have an enum:

```
A1 -> started
A2 -> running
```

In my database, I only save:

```
A1
B2
```

So, my query returns the column including strings such as:

```
A1
B2
```

I'd like obtaining:

```
started
running
```

Is it possible with a query?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT ...
,      CASE Column
         WHEN 'A1' THEN 'started'
         WHEN 'B2' THEN 'running'
         ... END AS Status
FROM Table
```

Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @M.Love, you're welcome. Please accept my answer if it works for you

Comment: Case _expression_...